# Time Series in R with Categorical and Continuous Variables

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data

I am having facing an issue with time series. I have collected data over an 18 hour time period of 1.Heart Rate 2. Running Time in HH:MM:SS.O and 3. the associated behaviour (either active or sedentary). The issue is that the data frame has over 18 hours of recorded entries (~250,000 rows) marked as either active or sedentary. I want to be able to distinguish between the different behaviours and am trying to calculate the duration each time an Active period starts until it is ended by a Stationary period. I then want to be able to calculate the average heart-rate for these time periods... is there anyway in which I can write this in R? Thank you!